# How do i delete directory's in Linux (without first deleting the files inside)

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I just gotten a Raspberry Pi for Christmas and I wanted to delete some built in programs because I wanted to make a Linux server for home use. So far I had to do this all the time using the terminal because to delete the files, you had to use root.

```
rm ./files/*
rmdir files
```

Is there any way I can use `rmdir` command when there are files in it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming. The question should be asked at http://superuser.com/ or at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rm -rf files` will remove the `files` directory and all subdirectories **and** not prompt you with questions about file permissions.

Comment: This is the answer you are looking for, but I'd caution that you need to be careful with `rm -rf whatever/`. This will delete everything in that folder, along with the folder itself without a prompt. Don't start deleting large sections of you file system, or you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: **Absolutely**. Treat it as carefully as `rm -r * `

Comment: Be aware of uninitialized or empty variable in `rm -rf /$files`

Comment: And just because the OP is a kid, note that `rm` first appeared in 1971 with Version 1 of AT&T Unix. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix#/media/File:Unix_history-simple.svg

Comment: Thank you, I was new to Linux, (other than Android.)

Answer (score 2):

Sure just recursive delete :)

```
rm -r files
```

Comment: I find this not very descriptive or understanding.

Answer (score 1):

In your terminal, change directories to the one in the hierarchy just above the directory in question. Then:

`$mv ./dir_to_del/* .; rmdir ./dir_to_del`

This will move all the files out of the directory you want to delete, and then delete the now-empty folder.

Comment: Imo, the question is about deleting the directory as well as the contained files in one shot.

Comment: That's what i have been doing the whole time.

Comment: @PattonPierce, I was just covering all the bases. Your question is, in my opinion, ambiguously worded.  Now, for the fun stuff!  First: Welcome to the world of open computing! I want to encourage you to continue exploring computers and electronics, because these technologies will show you some marvelous things if you let them. Don't get discouraged and quit! Second: I see that you've discovered the `root` account and the power it can wield with with `rm`.  **Beware the power of the darkside** and use those tools with caution! You can really wreck your system with them :)

Comment: I knew about from since Mac OS X. But to use it on Debian Linux, instead of using su and a password, you had to use sudo su.

Comment: @PattonPierce, you shouldn't have to use `sudo` and `su` in conjunction if `/etc/sudoers` is properly configured.  Do a little reading and see if you can add your ordinary user account to `sudoers` if you haven't already done so, but be super careful! a mis-configured sudoers file can ruin your ability to escalate privileges.